# Find coefficients $a_n$, n $\subset$ **N**

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Find coefficients $a_n$, n $\subset$ **N**
Such that the function f given by :

$f(x)$=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$

Statisfy the equation:
$f''(x)$+$x^2f'(x)$+$xf(x)$=0,  $f(0)$=1, $f'(0)$=1

Give $a_0...,a_3$ explicit. Determine the radius of convergence.

Now i did the algebra regarding the power series and ended up with

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2) a_{n+2}x^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)a_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n$ = 0

And now i was trying to find the coefficients by using number plug in for:

$n=0$: (1)(2)$a_2$=0 so $a_2$=0 
For $n=1$: (2)(3)$a_3$+$a_0$=0 so  now i dont know what i should do next? Should i use the fact that $f(0)=1$ so that means that $a_0$=1? Then it follows that $a_3$=-1/6 but then i know that the Taylor series will be the function $sin(x)$ and that will start with 0 so $a_0$=0. What am i doing wrong? Please help..

Comment: Hello ? Does my post has been seen?

Comment: a lot of times I believe!!

Comment: @MayankM. Can you see my fault in reasoning? I was waiting a long time for a response though.

Comment: first i would shift all sums to the same base:

Comment: @Mark. I'm really sorry, but I've not learnt this, I'm a high-school student. If I would have known Taylor Series etc. then I would have solved it.

Comment: @arashjavan didnt i do that already? When all the sums have $x^n$ as base?

Comment: $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}x^n + (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n+2}+a_nx^{n+1}) = 0 $$

Comment: @arashjavan yes but now if we want to see what $a_0$ will be we get from the condition that $a_0$=0 because f(0)=0 right? But then i could not calculate $a_3$=-1/6 because then $a_0$=1 you see my point?

Comment: @Mark, well actually $a_0 = 1$, $$ f(0) = 1 \rightarrow a_0+a_10^1+a_20^2+\cdots+ \rightarrow a_0 = 1 $$

Comment: @arashjavan then is the initial condition f(0)=0 stated wrong? And should it been f(0)=1?

Comment: take a look here : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TaylorSeries.aspx

Comment: @arashjavan yes thank you i see that sinx= 1/1!x so f(0)=1 not f(0)=0?!